# CakePHP generatetreelist error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I used this tutorial for my Menu (navigation) in CakePHP

http://my-cakephp.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-create-category-tree-with.html

but i get this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'generatetreelist' at line 1
```

Comment: please anyone who know for Tree Behaviours and can help me.. thanks to all

Comment: Can you post your sql statement?

Comment: i dont have ane other statement, just i get this:
http://s21.postimg.org/mmzjqs0g6/Capture.jpg

Comment: I mean the sql code. As I have seen the tutorial is from 2009 and now we have 2013. So I'm sure that inbetween some has been changed in php and therefore the sql query is not working anymore.

Comment: Note that $actsAs needs to be spelled correctly, my money is on the incorrect spelling, thus the behavior is never really attached. Also, first look in the official documentation, not some outdated blog post.

Answer (score 0):

The method [generatetreelist()](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-TreeBehavior.html#_generatetreelist) is from CakePHP 1.3 version, if you're using a newer version of CakePHP the method has been renamed to [generateTreeList()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-TreeBehavior.html#_generateTreeList)